# Storing a set of arrays of different types

Tags: c++

As a matter of interest, lets say I have the following class:

```
class Data
{
public:
    template<class T>
    std::vector<T> getData(std::string& dataName);
private:
    ...
}:
```

So the class stores a set of vectors of any type. Each vector has a name and I know its type when retrieving it. What container might I use to store this data within the Data class? A `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::vector<T>>>`?

**UPDATE**:

I will also need to iterate over this class and the items must be in the same orders as I added them.

For example, I might have:

```
ownerNames: std::vector<std::string>;
ipAddress: std::vector<char>;
```

in my store. So when I iterate I need them in this order.

Comment: Do the vectors contain a single type each? (each vector has different type)

Comment: OK, so your example is just screaming "you are doing it so very wrong"!

Comment: No, its as it should be. I've made a better example.

Comment: @Baz: So, in your updated example, is there a relation between the data in `ownerNames` and `ipAddress`. If not, they should be in two different `Data` classes, if there is a relations, that relation should be encapsulated into another class.

Comment: @Skizz Yes they are related. Lets say that we have a server with an ip address and a set of owners. I'm not in charge of this data format, rather the model I'm working with.

Comment: @Baz: Is the model fixed? If so, then create classes to represent the model directly. If it's not fixed then how are you ever going to know what's in the data at run time and what type it is? Templates are not run time dynamic types, i.e. you can't have a `vector<float>` created if there is no code anywhere to do it explicitly, i.e. `new vector<float>` must exist in the code somewhere. If nothing creates the `vector<float>` and the model requires one, then you're out of luck. If `vector<any>` is the only solution, then use a programming language that supports dynamic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the type upon retrieval, use a `boost::any`:

```
struct Data
{
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> store;

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> & get(std::string const & s)
    {
        boost::any & a = store.find(s)->second;       // check existence!
        return boost::any_cast<std::vector<T> &>(a);  // try/catch bad cast!
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool put(std::string const & s, std::vector<T> v)
    {
        return store.emplace(s, std::move(v)).second;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
void f(Data & d)
{
    try
    {
        auto & v = d.get<int>("MyNumbers");
    }
    catch (boost::bad_any_cast const & e)
    {
        std::cout << "'MyNumbers' is not an int-vector.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution gives me the heebiejeebies. Does the `any_cast<>` do run time type checking (even with rtti)? What if the entry named "MyNumbers" was a vector of floats?

Comment: @Skizz: That's a runtime exception.

Comment: @MSalters: I just noticed I typed 'with rtti', I meant 'without rtti'. Would prefer a non-exception generating solution.  Still, I think the OP is trying to put a square peg into a round hole by hitting it really hard.

Comment: @Skizz The store corresponds to how data is stored in a model.

Comment: @Skizz: `any` is fine and type-safe. You just have to remember what you put in. There's just a small cost of a virtual function call.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I need to preserve the order of insertion. I've updated my OP to clarify this

Comment: @Baz: I thought you wanted lookup by a string?! Which one do you want? You can make the map key a `pair<int, string>` if that helps.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I will be looking up only be name, but I need to convert this store to another memory arrangement before passing it to a C api after I'm finished with it. And for this purpose, I need the items stored in a specific order.

Comment: @Baz: You can't "iterate" over this structure. You need to know the type of each element, and you can't iterate over types.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Shouldn't your example be `d.get <vector<int>>(...)` to get an int-vector.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm currently seeing `d.get<int>(...)`

Comment: @Skizz: Sorry, no, all is well.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry, my bad, didn't pick up on the return type of `get`

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `boost::any`.

```
typedef std::vector<boost::any> any_vector;

std::map<std::string, any_vector> data;
```

Comment: Is that a vector of objects of any type? I think the OP wanted vectors of a single type, but a set of them, each item named.

Comment: Vector of any, or any vector? I went for the opposite reading :-)

Comment: @Nawaz std::map will iterate based on name, right? I need to iterate based on order of insertion.

Comment: @Baz: Then use `std::vector<std::pair< ... >>`. :-)

Answer (score -1):

OK, based on the latest comment, I suggest a class like this:-

```
class Server
{
public:
  const IPAddress GetIPAddress ();
  vector <std::string> &GetOwners ();
};
```

where `IPAddress` is a helper class to store an IP address and access it in various ways (four chars, string, int, etc...).

I really wouldn't try to force the same access style onto the two different data collections (IP address, owner names).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for anything like this. I need a container which stores multiple std::vector<T> where T can be of any type.

Comment: @Baz: Good luck with that, I don't know of any way to do: `std:vector <std::vector <type>>` that has different values for `type` for each entry in the outer vector.

Comment: @Skizz: Type erasure. That's what it's for :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I totally forgot about the whole `void *` solution!